# Static files not showing in Django 1.9.5

Tags: python, django, static

My static files aren't showing and I can't figure out why. Below is my directory:

```
- mb <app_name>
    -src
        -mb
        -static
            - static_dirs
            - static_root
        -templates
```

my settings.py file looks as such:

```
import os

BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
# print "This is base ", BASE_DIR

DEBUG_CONST = True

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
TEMPLATE_DEBUG = DEBUG_CONST
DEGUB = DEBUG_CONST
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*']
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "templates")],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'mb.context_processors.init',
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
                'social.apps.django_app.context_processors.backends',
                'social.apps.django_app.context_processors.login_redirect',
            ],
        },
    },
]

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static", "static_dirs"),
)
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static", "static_root")
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static', 'media_root')
```

my urls:

```
 from django.conf.urls import include, url, patterns
    from django.conf.urls.static import static
    urlpatterns = patterns(
    '',
    url(r'^$', 'mb.views.login_view', name='login'),
) + static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT) + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

in my base template I have this snippet:

```
{% load staticfiles %}
<!doctype>
<html>
<head>
    <title>MB</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'css/main.css' %}">
    <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Ceviche+One' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Arimo' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <!-- bxSlider CSS file -->
    <link href="{% static 'js/lib/jquery.bxslider/jquery.bxslider.css' %}" rel="stylesheet"/>
</head>
```

This is my views:

```
from django.shortcuts import render, render_to_response
from django.template.context_processors import csrf
def login_view(request):
    # c = get_base_context(request)
    c = {}
    c.update(csrf(request))
    return render_to_response('download.html', c)
```

This is what my error log tells me:

```
    Exception while resolving variable 'request' in template 'download.html'.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 905, in _resolve_lookup
    (bit, current))  # missing attribute
VariableDoesNotExist: Failed lookup for key [request] in u'[{\'False\': False, \'None\': None, \'True\': True}, {u\'csrf_token\': <SimpleLazyObject: u\'WOTjM9l9i0UAGyzVE2K039tkteP3Z0nk\'>}, {\'block\': <Block Node: content. Contents: [<TextNode: u\'\\n<style type="text/css">\\n\'>, <django.template.defaulttags.URLNode object at 0x1111b7910>, <TextNode: u\'" style="color:white">ABO\'>, <django.contrib.staticfiles.templatetags.staticfiles.StaticFilesNode object at 0x1111b79d0>, <TextNode: u\'" alt="" height="600" sty\'>, <django.contrib.staticfiles.templatetags.staticfiles.StaticFilesNode object at 0x1111b7a90>, <TextNode: u\'" alt="" class="third_ima\'>, <django.contrib.staticfiles.templatetags.staticfiles.StaticFilesNode object at 0x1111b7b50>, <TextNode: u\'" type="video/mp4"/>\\n    \'>, <django.contrib.staticfiles.templatetags.staticfiles.StaticFilesNode object at 0x1111b7c10>, <TextNode: u\'" type="video/mp4"/>\\n    \'>, <django.contrib.staticfiles.templatetags.staticfiles.StaticFilesNode object at 0x1111b7cd0>, <TextNode: u\'" type="video/ogg"></sour\'>, <TextNode: u\'" ng-submit="preregister_\'>, <django.template.defaulttags.CsrfTokenNode object at 0x1111b7d50>, <TextNode: u\'\\n\\t                       \'>, <django.template.defaulttags.URLNode object at 0x1111b7e10>, <TextNode: u\'" class="text-sm">Forgot \'>, <TextNode: u\'?next=\'>, <Variable Node: request.path>, <TextNode: u\'" type="submit" class="bt\'>]>}]'
Not Found: /static/css/main.css
Not Found: /static/js/lib/jquery.bxslider/jquery.bxslider.css
Not Found: /static/js/require.js
Not Found: /static/img/iphone-frame.png
Not Found: /static/img/guy_with_box.png
Not Found: /static/video/featured_video.mp4
Not Found: /static/js/require.js
Not Found: /static/video/featured_video.mov
```

I've tried downgrading my django to 1.8, that doesn't seem to work, I also tried putting the static folder in different paths and linking to it in settings.py and nothing works. My templates show up just fine which makes it even more confusing.

Comment: I would first fix the exception that is being thrown about not being able to resolve the variable 'request' in your template 'download.html'.

Comment: is `BASE_DIR` pointing to the correct directory? Because when I look at this structure, to me it looks like there's an `src` missing in all three of `MEDIA_ROOT`, `STATIC_ROOT`, and `STATICFILES_DIRS`.

Comment: @dhke It's definitely in the right place. Like I mentioned before, I have my templates in the same directory and when I move them to another directory I get an error but I will try adding src in there to see if it makes a difference

Comment: @user4426017 I have edited the question to include my views. As you can see I don't know why I am getting the 'request' error

Comment: @user875139 Don't bother, I didn't read the template part. As for more debugging: `manage.py findstatic -v3 css/main.css` should give you a list of locations tried. And also try with `{% load static %}`. I'm pretty sure `{% load staticfiles %}` is deprecated nowadays.

Comment: @dhke thanks for the help when I ran a findstatic it brought this. /Users/mac/Documents/python_dev/mb/src/static/static_dirs.                 When I print out staticdir_files I get /Users/mac/Documents/python_dev/mb/static/static_dirs                      Guess you're right needs to add src in the path

Comment: @user875139 Seems correct. And the templates are found because of `'APP_DIRS': True,` via the secondary resolver.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/121195/discussion-between-user875139-and-dhke).